# Add text input in addition to the select

Tags: python, html, django

```
execution_time = models.IntegerField(
    choices=((i, i) for i in (15, 30, 45, 60)),
    blank=False,
    default=30,
    verbose_name='estimated time'
)
```

I want to add 60+ execution time. Requirement is to add a text input in addition to the select.

Anyone with an idea how to implement it here? Will I be able to get a text area also in the choices where I can provide the integer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't represent 60+ as an integer - you should be using a `CharField`:

```
execution_time = models.CharField(
    choices=((i, i) for i in ('15', '30', '45', '60', '60+')),
    blank=False,
    default='30',
    verbose_name='estimated time'
)
```

If you just want '60+' as an option, then the above will work. If you want to allow users to enter whatever they want, then you can't use choices, you're going to have to write a custom widget, and write some JavaScript most likely.

Comment: I want to allow users to write in a time greater than 60. But that would be taken as 60+ in filters.

Comment: execution_time = models.IntegerField(
        choices=((i, i) for i in ('15', '30', '45', '60', '60+')),
        blank=False,
        default='30',
        verbose_name='estimated time'
    )
    
This gives me an option to select 60+. Will it be possible to add a text area near to this select- where I can add in a number greater than 60?